# How to create a directory recursively in C++ that exceeds MAX_PATH?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, directory

I've been trying to create a folder recursively, meaning when I input

`"C:\\test\\aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabaaabaababbaabababaabbababababaabababbabab\\22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222\\12345");`

it would create every folder that isn't there up until the last entry. I've tried SHCreateDirectoryExW, but that one does not accept paths longer than MAX_PATH, not even with the special prefix. Is there an already existing function that does this with up to 32k characters or do I have to create one myself? I can create a normal folder, given that the folders above exist, just fine.

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity, why do you need to do this?

Comment: This might be needed to install a malware that will fool common security programs :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to create each directory on the path individually. Parse the path into its directory components, and then work through them one by one. When you encounter a directory that does not exist, create it, and move on to the next level down.

The API function that you need to use here is `CreateDirectory`. Pass it the full path to the directory that you need to create. You'll need to use the Unicode version of the API, with the `\\?\` prefix to disable the `MAX_PATH` length limit.

Comment: You need to be unicode compatible though and therefore use `CreateDirectoryW`. Using `CreateDirectoryA` does not support long paths.

Comment: @Benoit The answer already says that. *You'll need to use the Unicode version of the API, with the \\?\ prefix to disable the MAX_PATH length limit.*

Comment: While technically possible it's **not a good idea to do this**, because e.g. Windows Explorer, and most other programs, as well as some APIs such as the shell utility functions, are limited `MAX_PATH`. An ordinary end user might find it difficult to remove or inspect such a directory.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf You meant to attach that comment to the question surely

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I meant to attach it to this answer. IMO it's information that belongs in the answer, for answer readers in general to see, e.g. coming in via Google. However, I try to not edit others' answers. ;-)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf What if my answer does not endure? What if a different one is added that is accepted? Why my answer but not Joachim's? Frankly, your comment concerns the question that was asked, and the premise under which it was asked.

Comment: Well if a man is drowning then I'll wait in case a whole family suddenly appears in the water, more needing my help. Heh. I think the answer is otherwise OK.

Answer (score 0):

Split the path into its components. Check that each of these components exists, or create then one by one, while setting the applications current directory to the directory. This way you don't deal with the complete path, only one (relative) component at a time.

So something like this pseudo-code:

```
split_path();
set_cwd(root);
for (i = 0; i < number_of_components; ++i)
{
    if (!does_path_exits(component[i]))
        makedir(component[i]);
    set_cwd(component);
}
```

Comment: Modifying working directory is bad practice. That affects the entire process so this code can have impact on other threads. It's just a big nasty global variable. `CreateDirectoryW` with `\\?\` is the mechanism that is needed here.

Comment: @Liviu That doesn't excuse it in my view. If you want something that works on multiple platforms, wrap it up in a helper function which has platform specific implementations.

Comment: @David Heffernan A while ago "we" needed this on Mac OS X, BSD API had same limitation (or almost ... PATH_MAX was the name), but no `\\?\` mechanism so it was the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I've succumbed to Boost, mainly because it is only 1 line I needed to add in.

```
std::tstring widePath = WIDEPATH_PREFIX;
widePath += CStringW(filePath.c_str());
return (boost::filesystem::create_directories(widePath));
```

I simply attached the prefix to my filepath and sent it off to boost.